# partitioning by more than 1 field in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, windowing

I Can't figure out how to partition by more than 1 field in tableau.

Data landscape - I have 2 dimension fields:  id (string) and platformtype (str).  I have 2 measures: total_usage(float) and month (int).  Using Tableau Desktop 10.3.3 on a mac.

Goal - I am trying to create a view with a single bar chart that shows the top N ids by total_usage in a given month.  I'd like to filter by month and by platform_type, and to be able to change N (say, in the range of 5 - 25 in steps of 5).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you you place month on the filter shelf, add it to the context. Then you will first filter by month before applying other filters, such as the top N filter on ids.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that worked!  I actually had to add both the month and the platformtype fields to the context (ie - make them both context filters), but it's working great!